# Cannot modify BIOS setting on Asus Zenbook UX31a

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, asus-laptop, secure-boot

I bought an Asuz Zenbbok UX31A with windows 8 a while ago. After I bought it I decided to put windows 7 on it and everything worked fine. Yesterday I updated my bios in order to fix a fan issue and it was flashed successfully (as far as I know).

After restarting the computer it now goes straight to BIOS, it doesn't find any partitions that it can boot to.

I believe the issue is because the "Launch CSM" option is disabled, but I cannot enable it, it is greyed out. Does anybody know how I can get it to let me change the setting? (Or is there something else I could do?)

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should contact Asus for a possible solution.  Sounds like the flashing process reset the BIOS configuration to the default which is not compatabile with your current configuration.

Answer (score 6):

this is for anyone searching for the Launch CSM disabled (greyed out) issue (can't enable it) it's because Secure Boot is enabled in the BIOS. Disable it, then reboot and go back into BIOS and you should be able to enable Launch CSM.